# Run python code which is served via flask in javascript when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm trying to run some python code which is served via Flask and I want that python code to return a value to javascript so that I can use it there.

In this case, I have a button in HTML, When I hit it, I want a python code (served via Flask) to run and it should return "Hello" which I can use it in HTML like displaying it or storing it another variable.

Here are my codes:

`ajax.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>country</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

<button id="btn" onclick="flaskcall()">display</button>
<p id="display-here">Display here {{ temp }}</p>
<script>


function flaskcall()
{
    $.ajax(
  {
     type: "POST",
     url: "/hello",
     dataType: "html",
     success: function(msg)
     {
         console.log(msg);
             $("#display-here").html(msg);

     },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

});
}

 </script>

</body>

</html>
```

`flaskajax.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/hello", methods=['GET', 'POST'])


def Hello():
    message = "Hello"
    return render_template("ajax.html", temp=message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`webserver.py`

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8888

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

What I'm doing is, I'm running `webserver.py` and I'm navigating to `http://localhost:8888/ajax.html` and when I press `display` button I'm seeing this error

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0fco.png)

I don't even know If I'm doing it in the right way or not, I don't understand the GET and POST methods also. If anyone understood what I'm actually trying to do and if they can explain to me what really is happening behind the hood, I will be grateful. Please comment if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your 2nd server, using flask:

```
from flask import Flask, Response

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/ajax")
def Hello():
    resp = Response("Hello")
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return resp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Of crucial importance is setting the header as shown, otherwise the browser will not allow the AJAX request since it's to a different server.

In your `index.html` put this in the `<body>` for now:

```
<h1>Hello from Flask.</h1>
<button id="btn" onclick="flaskcall()">display</button>
<p id="display-here"></p>
<script>
    function flaskcall() {
        fetch("//localhost:5000/ajax").then(res => res.text()).then(res => {
            document.querySelector("#display-here").textContent = res;
        });
    }
</script>
```

The function will use AJAX to request `GET /ajax` from the flask server, to which the server will reply `Hello`.
Then the response is inserted into the document (using the non-jQuery version to be safe).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!. However, your solution is requiring me to run the flask file. `index.html` is my main file and I need a local host to run that file. I want the python code to run and return a value after I hit a button from `index.html`. I pasted the same code you suggested and it is giving me `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` when I press the button. Can you please look into it.

Comment: A Flask() app contains a web server. By default it's reachable at http://localhost:5000. You don't need a separate one. If you do run two of them - Flask *and* your webserver.py - you'll only run into CORS issues. Anyway, I'm perfectly aware of what you're trying to do, and my code does exactly that. The HTML code I posted is supposed to replace what you have in `<body>`; you apparently removed everything else, including the jQuery script, which is what causes the error. Keep your HTML, but put my code between `<body>` and `</body>`.

Comment: If you do want to use two servers, you need to make a request for `http://localhost:5000/ajax.html`, and there's no need to send back an entire HTML file if all you want is insert some text in a `<p>`.

Comment: Yeah, Even I thought so. But, I pasted your code in the body part of my `index.html`.  I did not remove the entire code. this is the code I'm running https://pastebin.com/embed_js/nTg3fD8v

Comment: My actual problem: I have an `index.html` which has some other algorithms doing certain tasks. I definitely need a local server to test them. There is a new task for which using python is much easier...So...I created a new button on `index.html`. When I click that button, I need the python code to run for me. The python code has to do some complex operations and it finally returns a string. I want that string to be returned to the `index.html` and I can carry further operations with that string. I want to know if that is possible, I don't even know if flask is required or not.

Comment: So are you using `SimpleHTTPServer` as your main server?

Comment: exactly!! I'll host the `index.html` using `webserver.py` or `python -m http.server`

Comment: Alright, I've changed my answer accordingly. It should work now for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the patience. In mozilla I'm running into this `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/ajax. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).` and in chrome I'm running into `net:: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` and `TypeError: Failed to fetch`. Can you please look into it?

Comment: @VinayVarma You did change the Flask script according to my answer though, right? Because the CORS error you mention is prevented by `resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'` and it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Yeah, I got it working now. When I hosted `index.html` through `webserver.py` and I got the `Fetch failed loading: GET "http://localhost:5000/ajax"`. So, I opened another terminal and I hosted `flaskajax.py` and now It is running perfectly. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: One last doubt, Suppose I deployed `index.html` at SiteA with domain `SiteA.com` (which is the main domain for my web app) and now I want to use the python code, should I deploy `flaskajax.py` at SiteB with domain `SiteB.com` so that when I press a button at SiteA, It can send a request to SiteB? Is this how they do it? Is there a way to test it in the above way? maybe through AWS EC2 instance or Heroku?

Comment: The `fetch()` command needs the proper URL; as long as the flask server sets the header appropriately, requesting resources from another domain isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running webserver.py which has nothing to do with your flask application.

you should run it as :

python flaskajax.py

which will run its own webserver and listens on default 5000 and you can browse to http://localhost:5000/hello

Some issues with your code though, you forgot to import render_template. Here is how it should be,

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/hello", methods=['GET', 'POST'])


def Hello():
    message = "Hello"
    return render_template("ajax.html", temp=message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks!! it's working. But I need the webserver.py because the ajax.html is actually an index.html (main file ) for my web app with other algorithms running in javascript. To test those algorithms I need a local server. I need this python code to run when I open `index.html` and hit a button. Your solution is requiring me to run the flask file.